# Load an Array ordered by Alphabetical letters

Tags: php, html, arrays

I have an array of users, Like so :

```
Andrew Smith
Alex Williams    
Sam White
Stuart Smith
```

I am looking to use [iOSList](http://brianhadaway.github.io/iOSList/) to create a list that would look like so....

```
A
Andrew Smith
Alex Williams

S
Sam White
Stuart Smith
```

I have made an attempt at this using a PHP Foreach loop and a break, But each user has a seperate ul each time.

My current code is as follows :

```
        <?php
        $currentLetter = '';
        foreach($pupils['user'] as $pupil)
        {
            $firstLetter = substr($pupil->profile_name, 0, 1);
        ?>
        <?php
            if ($firstLetter !== $currentLetter) { ?>
                <!-- SHOW FIRST LETTER -->
                    <div class="ioslist-group-container">
                        <div class="ioslist-group-header">
                            <strong>
                                <?php echo $firstLetter; ?>
                            </strong>
                        </div><!-- /.ioslist-group-header -->
                <?php $currentLetter = $firstLetter; ?>
            <?php } ?>
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/pupil/view'); ?>/<?php echo $pupil->user_id; ?>">
                            <?php echo $pupil->profile_name; ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.iostlist-group-container -->
        <?php } // END FOREACH  ?>
```

My HTML is being outputted as this :

```
<div id="pupil-list">
                                                <!-- SHOW FIRST LETTER -->
                    <div class="ioslist-group-container">
                    <div class="ioslist-group-header">
                        <strong>
                            A                       </strong>
                    </div><!-- /.ioslist-group-header -->
                                                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://local.wld-hub/admin/pupil/view/10">
                            Adam Bragg                      </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div><!-- /.iostlist-group-container -->
                                                <!-- SHOW FIRST LETTER -->
                    <div class="ioslist-group-container">
                    <div class="ioslist-group-header">
                        <strong>
                            S                       </strong>
                    </div><!-- /.ioslist-group-header -->
                                                    <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://local.wld-hub/admin/pupil/view/11204">
                            Sam acclaiminapp                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div><!-- /.iostlist-group-container -->
                                            <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="http://local.wld-hub/admin/pupil/view/11194">
                            Sam NormalEmail                     </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                </div>
```

The last 2 elements are breaking out of the "**pupil-list**"

[image: broken menu]

Where am I going wrong and how can I correct it?

Cheers

Comment: Is the list always sorted by first letter?

Comment: Hi @Jack yes it is. The data is from an API and I've requested it to be that way

Comment: And what is your problem. There are some invalid HTML, because you are opening closing `divs`  in foreach, but the result seems good to me except this.

Comment: Hi @lolka_bolka I suspect the HTML being invalid is my issue, I've modified my answer to show the outputted HTML and a screenshot

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You make user list with only one item each time.

```
<?php
// Display user list
$currentLetter = '';
foreach($pupils['user'] as $pupil)
{
    $firstLetter = $pupil->profile_name[0];
    if($firstLetter !== $currentLetter)
    {
        // If it's not the first loop, we close the list and block containers
        if($currentLetter !== '')
        {
        ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <?php
        }
    ?>
        <!-- SHOW FIRST LETTER -->
        <div class="ioslist-group-container">
            <div class="ioslist-group-header">
                <strong><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></strong>
            </div><!-- /.ioslist-group-header -->
            <ul>
    <?php
    }
?>
                <li><?php echo $pupil->profile_name; ?></li>
<?php
}
// Close the last list and block containers
?>
            </ul>
        </div>
<?php
// End of display
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't like the mixing of PHP and HTML in your example. I prefer to go for all PHP code. Your basic idea is correct but it would become:

```
function showFirstLetter($letter)
{
  echo '<div class="ioslist-group-header"><strong>'.$letter.'</strong></div>';
}

function showPupilName($pupil)
{
  $url = base_url('admin/pupil/view').'/'.$pupil->user_id;
  echo '<li><a href="'.$url.'">'.$pupil->profile_name.'</a></li>';
}

echo '<div class="ioslist-group-container">'; // start container

$currentLetter = '';
foreach($pupils['user'] as $pupil)
{
  $firstLetter = substr($pupil->profile_name,0,1);
  if ($firstLetter !== $currentLetter) 
  { 
    if ($currentLetter != '') echo '</ul>'; // end list
    showFirstLetter($firstLetter);
    $currentLetter = $firstLetter; 
    echo '<ul>'; // start list
  } 
  showPupilName($pupil);
} 

echo '</ul></div>'; // end last list and container
```

Lots of things can be improved in this code, but when your code is more legible you can see your error much quicker. In this case the `ul` list tags were the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The problem seems to be that you're not properly closing your elements at the end of each group; you could check whether `$firstLetter` is empty and close `</div>` if it's not (empty); this would have to be repeated at the end as well.

Alternatively, build an intermediate structure:

```
$tmp = [];
foreach ($pupils['user'] as $pupil) {
    $tmp[$pupil->profile_name[0]][] = $pupil->profile_name);
}

foreach ($tmp as $letter => $names) { ?>
    <div class="ioslist-group-container">
      <div class="ioslist-group-header">
        <strong><?php echo $firstLetter; ?></strong>
      </div>
      <ul>
      <?php foreach ($names as $name) { ?>
        <li>
          <a href="<?php echo base_url('admin/pupil/view') . '/' . $pupil->user_id; ?>"><?php echo $pupil->profile_name; ?></a>
        </li>
      <?php } ?>
      </ul>
    </div>
<?php }
```

Keep in mind that you should escape your output using either `htmlspecialchars()` or `urlencode()` depending on what's being escaped.